# Django is not updating my model objects instead they created new

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, python-requests

So this is my simple function which is working fine. Basically it's extracting data from this site.

```
def mega():
    pageNumber = 1
    nextPage = True
    proList = []
    while nextPage:
        url = "http://www.mega.pk/mobiles/{}/".format(pageNumber)
        response = get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, features="lxml")
        ul = soup.find('ul', class_='item_grid list-inline clearfix')
        li = ul.find_all('li', class_='col-xs-6')
        if not li:
            break
        for link in li:
            if link.find("div", class_="was"):
                title = link.find(id="lap_name_div").text.replace("\n", "")
                data = link.find("div", class_="cat_price").text.replace(
                    "\n", "").replace("\t", "").replace(" ", "")
                lists = data.split("-")
                if len(lists) > 2:
                    price = lists[1].replace("PKR", "") + "-PKR"
                else:
                    price = data
                price = int(price.replace(",", "").replace(
                    '-', "").replace("PKR", ""))
                productUrl = link.find("a")['href']
                image = link.find("img")['data-original']
                pro = Product(title=title, price=price, productUrl=productUrl,imageUrl=image, site="mega.pk")
                proList.append(pro)    
        pageNumber = pageNumber + 1
    return proList
```

But following is my view in which when i try to assign item.price = product.price. then instead of updating it's creating new instance.

```
def scraper(request):
    products = mega()
    proList = Product.objects.all()
    for product in products:
        for item in proList:
            if product.title == item.title and product.price == item.price:
                break
            elif product.title == item.title and product.price != item.price:
                notify = Notification(user = request.user, changeMessage="Price updated")
                notify.save()
                item.price = product.price
                break

    return redirect("home")
```

Like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4e6xp.png)

Answer (score 0):

Since you fetch the items from your database with `proList = Product.objects.all()` and then iterate over it with `for product in products:`

You should change it from `item.price = product.price` to:

```
product.price = item.price
product.save()
```

Then you will update the existing record in the database with the new item you got from `mega()`